# Amazon SQS – Change the delivery time for each message individually (using boto3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs, boto

When processing a message from a standard queue (responding from a lambda function), how can I increase the delivery time for
that message next time it's added back to the queue, in case the processing fails?

Does boto3 offer an API for changing the delivery time on a message-level? (I've only seen it for the entire queue, so far).

Thanks!

Comment: If you feel that the linked answer is not appropriate for your situation (eg you are not using Lambda with SQS), feel free to reopen the question and add more details that are specific to your situation.

Comment: `SendMessage()` does have a `DelaySeconds` parameter, which can be used for each individual message. However, this value seems to be ignored when Amazon SQS is triggering an AWS Lambda function.